# Python Dataframe: If Date is Between Two Other Date Columns, Create New Column and Set Equal to 1

Tags: python, date, if-statement, field, between

I want to implement the following logic in a python dataframe:

1. If Date column is between StartDate and EndDate columns then:
2. Create a new column and set it equal to 1 (float) otherwise set equal to 0

My date columns have all been converted to datetime

I tried using a convoluted method of dong this with IntervalIndex and mapping:

```
df_EVENT5_16['PIT_FS'] = 1  

df_temp = df_EVENT5_16.filter(['PIT_FS', 'StartDate', 'EndDate'], axis =1)  

del df_EVENT5_16['PIT_FS']

s = pd.Series(df_temp['PIT_FS'].values, pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_temp['StartDate'], df_temp['EndDate']))

df_EVENT5_16['PIT_FS'] = df_EVENT5_16['DTIN'].map(s)
```

But the above attempt gave me the following error: `ValueError: cannot handle non-unique indices`

Is there an easier / more straightforward way to code the logic I'm after?

Answer (score -2):

```
def PIT_fleetsize(df):

        if  df['StartDate'] < df['DTIN'] < df['EndDate']:  
            val = 1
        else:
            val = 0

        return val

    df_EVENT5_16['Point In Time Fleet Size'] = df_EVENT5_16.apply(PIT_fleetsize, axis =1)
```

Comment: Improper code indentation is not valid Python code.